# Rotate GameObject on click

Tags: unity, quaternion

I'm trying to get a card to flip when clicked but the flipping only works the first flip. While debugging, I can see that OnMouse is called every time I click.

```
public class CardController : MonoBehaviour
{
   bool isShowingFront = true;
   bool isFlipping = false;
   float speed = 0.005F;
   Quaternion flipRotation = new Quaternion (0, 0, 0, 0);
   // Use this for initialization
   void Start ()
   {

   }

   // Update is called once per frame
   void Update ()
   {

      if (transform.rotation.y != flipRotation.y) {
             transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (transform.rotation, flipRotation, Time.deltaTime * speed);  
             isFlipping = true;                 
      } else {
             isFlipping = false;
      }

   }


   void OnMouseUp ()
   {          
      if (isShowingFront) {

             flipRotation.y = 180;

      } else {
             flipRotation.y = 0;
      }   

      isShowingFront = !isShowingFront;
      Debug.Log ("I was clicked");
   }
}
```

Comment: As a quick note, you can do this using [coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Coroutines.html). This helps to keep your `Update()` function clean, and you can store variables in the coroutine instead of having to put them on your class.

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter of the Lerp() method is the interpolation factor between *from* and *to* and should be between 0 and 1. Every time you flip a card you want to make this factor go from 0 to 1 over a period of time. You can do this as follows:

1. Add a float member variable *t*.
2. When the card is clicked set *t* to 0.
3. In your update function add `t += Time.deltaTime * speed; if(t > 1.0f) t = 1.0f;`
4. Pass *t* as the third parameter to the Lerp() method.

Note: if you can flip cards while they're still rotating, the rotation speed will not be constant this way. E.g. if flipping a card takes 1 second, flipping it again half way through will take 1 second as well instead of 0.5 second. You can make the speed constant by not setting *t* to 0 on click, but interpolating the value based on the current rotation.

Answer (score 0):

try working with the transform.Rotate(...) function. I think it's easier to use and it doesn't require quaternions.

As for your game logic I'd make a boolean which states if the card is flipped or not and according to that use the right transform.Rotate(...) function.